# Angular click event of dropdown child is fighting with dropdown event

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have simple custom dropdown with items in angular. When I focus out from dropdown or press enter `set` method is called

Problem is that when i click on `menu-item` method `setx` is not called but again method `set` from focus out. What can I do to call method from click event because only method from focusout is called.

```
<dropdown (keydown.enter)="set($event)" (focusout)="set($event)">
        <menu-item *ngFor="let val of values"
                      (click)="setx(val)">
        </menu-item>
    </dropdown>
```